# SQL Difference Between Sum of Two Months

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the difference between the previous years month and current years month. An example would be the SUM of sales for January 2013  and the difference of SUM of sales for January 2014 sales. This is being done to see how much we made from the previous year. I have a group by that shows the total sales by month and year. I'm having trouble on defining how to find the difference between the two months. Thank you for your help. Its greatly appreciated.

Table

```
Date      Sales
1/1/2013  100
1/12/2013 150
1/21/2013 90
1/4/2014  200
1/17/2014 50
1/20/2014 100
```

Result of Group By

```
Jan 2013
340

Jan 2014
350
```

Difference

```
Jan 2014 - Jan 2013
   340   -   350    = 10
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (the date format suggests probably MS SQL Server or Access)

Comment: The format that it comes into the system as mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on the database.  The first thing you need to do is to aggregate the data.  Then a simple join will get the data you need.  Here is one method:

```
with ym as (
      select year(date) as yr, month(date) as mon,
             sum(sales) as sales
      from table t
      group by year(date), month(date)
     )
select ym.yr, ym.mon, ym.sales, ymprev.sales as prev_sales,
       (ym.sales - ymprev.sales) as diff
from ym join
     ym ymprev
     on ymprev.yr = ym.yr - 1 and ymprev.mon = ym.mon;
```